# Discrete math set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

If a and b are finite sets then,

n(A∩B) = n(A)+n(B)-n(A∪B)

will this statement be false? and why please explain

Comment: Assuming that $n(X)$ denotes the number of elements in $X$, this statement is true always.

Comment: It is true even in the special case that A and B are disjoint. In that case, A∩B= empty, and n(A∩B) = 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Rewrite your equation as $|A\cup B| = |A|+|B| -|A\cap B|$ by adding $A\cup B$ to both sides and subtraction $A\cap B$ from both sides.

Here you can see the region I've labeled $C$ is $A\cap B$. When we take the cardinality of $A$ plus the cardinality of $B$ we count region $C$ twice. Therefore we have to subtract it to get the cardinality of $A\cup B$.